# Connector Transforms Incorrectly Maps Partition Key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a simple database table in MySQL that has `(id varchar(255), val varchar(255), ..., ...)`.

I set up Kafka Connect to stream the table to a topic (CONNECT_TOPIC) with twenty partitions.  I have another topic (STREAM_TOPIC) that is populated by a kafka producer with twenty partitions.

The problem is the keys from the connector map to different partitions in the CONNECTOR_TOPIC than the keys in the STREAM_TOPIC.  This means I can't join the two topics in a stream.  I believe this is because the id is extracted incorrectly.

Here is an example of that output:

```
Stream Task ID 0_13 Partition number 13 Consumed CONNECT_EVENT 68f52084-cfc9-4997-a28e-57cfd4f7bbbf
Stream Task ID 0_13 Partition number 13 Consumed JOINED CONNECT_EVENT 68f52084-cfc9-4997-a28e-57cfd4f7bbbf
Stream Task ID 0_17 Partition number 17 Consumed STREAM_EVENT 68f52084-cfc9-4997-a28e-57cfd4f7bbbf
Stream Task ID 0_17 Partition number 17 Consumed JOINED STREAM_EVENT 68f52084-cfc9-4997-a28e-57cfd4f7bbbf

Stream Task ID 0_7 Partition number 7 Consumed STREAM_EVENT 32aaa88d-b175-4a54-8338-d542ed051e6a
Stream Task ID 0_7 Partition number 7 Consumed JOINED STREAM_EVENT 32aaa88d-b175-4a54-8338-d542ed051e6a
Stream Task ID 0_17 Partition number 17 Consumed CONNECT_EVENT 32aaa88d-b175-4a54-8338-d542ed051e6a
Stream Task ID 0_17 Partition number 17 Consumed JOINED CONNECT_EVENT 32aaa88d-b175-4a54-8338-d542ed051e6a

Stream Task ID 0_11 Partition number 11 Consumed CONNECT_EVENT 90265a93-adac-4e93-856c-d1498eeeb22e
Stream Task ID 0_11 Partition number 11 Consumed JOINED CONNECT_EVENT 90265a93-adac-4e93-856c-d1498eeeb22e
Stream Task ID 0_11 Partition number 11 Consumed STREAM_EVENT 90265a93-adac-4e93-856c-d1498eeeb22e
Stream Task ID 0_11 Partition number 11 Consumed JOINED STREAM_EVENT 90265a93-adac-4e93-856c-d1498eeeb22e
Stream Task ID 0_11 Partition number 11 Merged 90265a93-adac-4e93-856c-d1498eeeb22e
```

I have tried the following connector configs to transform the id:

```
        "name": "CONNECTOR",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",

                "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",

                "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",

                "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
                "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",


                "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=rmoff&password=pw",

                "table.whitelist": "CONNECTOR",

                "mode": "timestamp",

                "timestamp.column.name": "update_ts",

                "validate.non.null": "false",

                "transforms":"createKey,extractId, castString",
                "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
                "transforms.createKey.fields":"id",
                "transforms.extractId.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
                "transforms.extractId.field":"id",
                "transforms.castString.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Key",
                "transforms.castString.spec": "string",

                "topic.prefix": "enrichment-"
        }
}
```

This extracts the ID perfectly, but maps to the wrong partition.  I also tried extractId instead of extractString, but the same thing happened.  I can't find clear documentation anywhere about how exactly to include these transforms.

Problem in a nutshell:

I need to extract the id field from the row, make it the record key, and make sure it does not act differently than using a kafka producer to do

`KafkaProducer.produce("string key", event)`

If I populate both topics with a producer they end up on the correct partitions, but something about connect is mapping to different partitions, even though it is the same key

Comment: Kafka Connect uses the same `DefaultPartitioner` that a Producer would, so are you using AvroConverter or StringConverter, becuase **that** would cause different partition calculations

Comment: I am not, I have schemas disabled and I am using JSON converter.  I added my full config above

Comment: Thanks. It's not really clear what the actual message is from the output you've shown, but if the key is just a string, not a nested value, can you try `StringConverter` instead?